# Anonymous innerclass declaration for an instance attribute, using another instance attribute

Tags: java, spring, guava, scjp

When using an anonymous innerclass inside a method, when we want to use a method parameter inside the anonymous innerclass, we must mark it as final.
Some details here:
[Why do we use final keyword with anonymous inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076773/why-do-we-use-final-keyword-with-anonymous-inner-classes)

But what happens when using a class attribute and not a method local attribute?

Simple usecase: a Spring service with a Guava function:

```
protected LovValueDAO lovValueDAO;

private final Function<String,LovValue> LOV_ID_TO_LOV = new Function<String,LovValue>() {
    @Override
    public LovValue apply(String input) {
        return lovValueDAO.findById(input);
    }
};

@Required
public void setLovValueDAO(LovValueDAO lovValueDAO) {
    this.lovValueDAO = lovValueDAO;
}
```

Is it secure to declare such a Guava function?
According to my tests it works fine but what happens behind the hood?

The initialization order is:

- Function is initialized
- lovValueDAO is injected by spring through the
  setter

Thus i guess, as the function is initialized first, that the lovValueDAO attribute used inside the function will not be a copy of the reference but the reference itself since once the DAO is really injected it works fine.

Am i correct?

---

And what happen if i use this code:

```
private final Function<String,LovValue> LOV_ID_TO_LOV = new Function<String,LovValue>() {
    @Override
    public LovValue apply(String input) {
        return lovValueDAO = null;
    }
};
```

Will my outside attribute `protected LovValueDAO lovValueDAO;` be set to null after i call the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inner class holds an implicit reference to `this` of its *enclosing instance* (i.e. an instance of its declaring class in context of which it was created), so that access to fields of the declaring class is treated as a normal field access by that reference.

So, your inner class will see the current value of the field, and can change it as well.