# How does the memory management of closures in Scala work?

Tags: scala, memory-management, closures

Scala allows closure like

```
def newCounter = {
  var a=0
  () => {a+=1;a}
}
```

which defines a function that on every call returns a new independent counter function starting at `1`:

```
scala> val counter1 = newCounter
counter1: () => Int = <function0>

scala> counter1()
res0: Int = 1

scala> counter1()
res1: Int = 2

scala> val counter2 = newCounter
counter2: () => Int = <function0>

scala> counter2()
res2: Int = 1

scala> counter1()
res3: Int = 3
```

This is quite impressive as usually `a` would be a representative of a memory address on the stack frame of newCounter. I've just read the closure chapter of "Programming in Scala" and it only has the following to say on that matter (p. 155):

> The Scala compiler rearranges things in cases like this so that the captured parameter lives out on the heap, instead of the stack, and thus can outlive the method call that created it. This rearrangement is all taken care of automatically, so you don't have to worry about it.

Can anyone elaborate on how this works on byte code level? Is the access similar to a member variable of a class with all the associated synchronization and performance implications?

Comment: This is called the "funarg problem", and I'm guessing wiki might have some pointers about the theorethical background: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funarg_problem. The general solution seems to be "put the activation record or parts of it on the heap". (Google might also be able to find some lecture slides / notes or papers about this.)

Comment: Note SIP 21 "spores" (whatta name!) http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831024/with-scala-closures-when-do-captured-variables-start-to-live-on-the-jvm-heap

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `scalac -Xprint:lambdalift <scala-file-name>` to investigate this.

Your code is actually something like this:

```
def newCounter = {
  val a: runtime.IntRef = new runtime.IntRef(0);
  new Function0 {
    private[this] val a$1 = a
    def apply() = {
      a$1.elem = a$1.elem + 1
      a$1.elem
    }
  }
}
```

There is a wrapper for any `var` used by lambda. Other `vars` (not used in closures) are common locale variables.

The link to this wrapper is stored as field in the instance of function.

`lambdalift` in `-Xprint:lambdalift` is the [compiler phase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528092/406435). You can get all phases with `-Xshow-phases`. You could use phase number instead of name, it's useful when you are not sure which phase you need.

Comment: What does the '20' mean in the cmd-line?

Comment: Btw, it would be interest to contrast that with another outer variable that is not used in the closure.

Comment: @pedrofurla: I've updated my answer. `20` was overkill, `lambdalift` (`15`) is enough.

Comment: @pedrofurla: `What does the '20' mean in the cmd-line?`... It's a funny way to [suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4023733/406435) [improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4528092/406435).

Comment: I wasn't suggesting an improvement, I was asking. I don't really care about SO rules much...

Comment: @pedrofurla: I mean there is already an answer to your question in **your** answers. There are links to 2 your answers in my comment.

Comment: @pedrofurla: I thought it's your way to suggest an improvement since you know an answer to the question.

Comment: LOL. More or less, I've never seen numbers used there, that was my curiosity.