# What does it mean to modify local variable from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, scala, jvm, stack

I wrote the following simple application:

```
object Main extends App {
    var v: Int = 0
    val t = new Thread(() =>  v = 1)
    t.start()
    t.join()
    println(v) //prints 1
}
```

The thing that I was confused by was that we modify local variable from another thread... And that modification (made by the other thread) is visible in the main thread.

I thought local variables are always reside in a stack (stack memory the bottom is pointed to `rsp` register). I thought the stack memory is allocated for each thread in the application.

Upd: Even if we modify the app as follows it prints the same:

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        var v: Int = 0
        val t = new Thread(() =>  v = 1)
        t.start()
        t.join()
        println(v) //prints 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`v` is not a local variable in this case. It is a member of `Main` singletone object.

Update for the second example: 
Closure `() => v = 1` is compiled into an anonymous class that captures all variables it depends on. Stack-allocated primitives are turned into heap-allocated objects. 
Here it is explained in details: 
[How does the memory management of closures in Scala work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134246/how-does-the-memory-management-of-closures-in-scala-work)

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

What this is doing is turning what appears to be a stack object into a heap object.  In Java you can do this using array of 1 without adding special classes as Scala does.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] v = { 0 };
    Thread t = new Thread(() => v[0] = 1);
    t.start();
    t.join();
    println(v[0]); //prints 1
}
```